# Refreshing master window in a splitview app (Titanium)

Tags: refresh, titanium-mobile, uisplitview

I am doing a Splitview App for iPad, I have to refresh my tableview (that is in my master _window) each time the user clicks on a button (this button is in the master_window but on another JavaScript file). How can I do this?

Comment: can you please show the code?

Comment: yes,thanks http://pastie.org/3768024

Answer (score 1):

Create a function inside your `MASTERWINDOW FILE` say

```
function updateTable(){ // update your table here};
```

Now, in you `App.js file`, include your `MASTERWINDOW FILE`

and do this:

```
Ti.App.updateTable= updateTable;
```

`Ti.App` Will make your function global, so that you can call it from any where in the app.
You can call it inside button click event.